# How to test java application for performance bottlenecks?

Tags: java, performance

I am reviewing a big java application to see if there are any performance bottlenecks. The real problem is that I cannot pinpoint the performance issues to any single module. The whole application is slow as such.

Is there some tool/technique I can use to help me out in this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using a profiler on your running code. It should help you identify the bottlenecks. Try [jprofiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) or [Netbeans profiler](http://www.netbeans.org/features/java/profiler.html)

Answer (score 6):

I'm often happy enough using `Java -Xprof`. This gives you a sorted list of the functions your code spends most of its time in.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running on Java 6 you can use the [supplied monitoring tools](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/monitoring/)

Answer (score 0):

For testing/development purposes, you can download Oracle JRockit Mission Control for free from [this](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/jrockit/index.html) site. (Requires Login, but accounts can be set up with any email adress)

Docs [Here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/jrockit/missioncontrol/index.html). It will allow you to find hotspots, memory leaks and much more.

Answer (score 0):

[YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/) is a excelent java profiler (not free).

Answer (score 0):

As we see from  [How can I profile C++ code running in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux), the most statistically significant approach is to use a stack profiler.

Well, Java runs in the JVM, so getting a stack useful for C code won't be useful for us (it'll get the JVM stuff, not your code). Fortunately, Java has `jstack`! http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstack.html

It'll give you a bunch of threads, like the GarbageCollector. Don't worry about those, just look at where your threads are.